# JavaScript Manualy Click run command but not working onload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, react-native

I am having anchor tag on my page. I like to trigger click event onload . This means I wanna open this Deep link for a React Native app "narvin://wallet" go to my app. The link is working if you manually click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function startMyApp() {                
            document.location = 'narvin://wallet';
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (confirm('You do not seem to have Your App installed, do you want to go download it now?')) {

                    document.location = 'https://cafebazaar.ir/app/cab.snapp.passenger';
                }
            }, 300);
        }
</script>
    <a href="#" onclick="startMyApp()" id="loader">Try to start MyApp </a>
```

, but not working onload page with this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById("loader").onclick();
                setTimeout(function () {                    
                    if (confirm('You do not seem to have Your App installed, do you want to go download it now?')) {

                        document.location = 'https://cafebazaar.ir/app/cab.snapp.passenger';
                    }
                }, 3000);
            };
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                document.location = 'narvin://wallet';
                setTimeout(function () {                    
                    if (confirm('You do not seem to have Your App installed, do you want to go download it now?')) {

                        document.location = 'https://cafebazaar.ir/app/cab.snapp.passenger';
                    }
                }, 3000);
            };
</script>
```

Comment: The third one *should* run. The second run won't run because you are calling `onclick` instead of `click`

Comment: I think the third one is ok but not working.
i use alert step by step for test and show alert before and after document.location = 'narvin://wallet';  but command not working . but when click manually it work .

Answer (score 0):

Your getElementById was returning a null because your script executes before the document is loaded. Window have to be called after all page content is loaded. You can use document.ready event instead of window.onload event